# Add animation in a sequence swift

Tags: ios, swift, animation

[image: Animation]

I am working with a Collection View and I have the following code to animate every cell with a `CATransform3DRotate`, using a small delay in is execution

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    guard let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as? RotationCollectionViewCell else {

        fatalError("\(String(RotationCollectionViewCell)) not found")
    }

    self.addAnimationToCells(cell)

    return cell
}
```

This is the code that animates the cells and creates the delay

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplayCell cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    self.delayTime += 0.05
    print(delayTime, "WILL DISPLAY DELAY TIME")
}

private func addAnimationToCells(cell : UICollectionViewCell) {


        let singleCell: UICollectionViewCell = cell
        let layer: CALayer = singleCell.layer

        layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.0)

        var transform = CATransform3DIdentity;
        transform.m34 = 1.0 / 500.0;
        transform = CATransform3DRotate(transform, CGFloat(90 * M_PI / 180), 1, 0, 0)
        singleCell.layer.transform = transform

        let start:CGFloat = 90
        let end:CGFloat = 0

        let rotationAnimation: CABasicAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation.x")
        rotationAnimation.fromValue = start.degreesToRadians
        rotationAnimation.toValue = end.degreesToRadians
        rotationAnimation.duration = 0.5
        rotationAnimation.repeatCount = 0
        rotationAnimation.removedOnCompletion = false
        rotationAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards
        rotationAnimation.delegate = CoreAnimationListener {
            finished in

            singleCell.layer.transform = CATransform3DIdentity

            singleCell.layer.removeAllAnimations()
        }

        print(delayTime, "THIS IS MY DELAY TIME")

        delay(delayTime){
            cell.layer.addAnimation(rotationAnimation, forKey: "transform.rotation.x")
        }   
}
```

The problem is that if I scroll I have a blank space. I think is because the very last cell that gets loaded it has animation added with an accumulated delay, so when I scroll it takes a bit to animate. I can't figure out how avoid adding the time delay to the last cell gets returned on load. Please help

Comment: Could you reset the delay on scrollViewDidEndDecelerating?

Comment: interesting, Well in this case I guess would be before scrolling... but is an interesting idea... I'll try

Comment: Did not work.. there has to be a better way to animate collectionView Cells in a sequence...

Comment: You should also `delayTime = 0.0` in `viewDidAppear`

Comment: @beyowulf It worked!... if you write it as an answer I'll give you the ticket!

Answer (score 0):

as @Beyowulf commented I only had to reset the delayTime to 0 in ViewDidAppear